# Button taking up whole screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-signin, flutter-web

I am building a webapp with flutter where I want to add google sign in. The button itself works fine, but whatever I try, it just takes up my whole screen. I tried putting the button in the class in a container and putting it in a container on the page I actually want to use it on. This is my first time with flutter web, so I'd really like to know why this is happening.

Here is my code for the button:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:foci_dev/pages/main_page.dart';
import 'package:foci_dev/repo/database_repo.dart';
import 'package:foci_dev/repo/init_repo.dart';
import 'package:foci_dev/service/authentication.dart';

class GoogleButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GoogleButtonState createState() => _GoogleButtonState();

  final DatabaseRepo databaseRepo;
  final InitRepo initRepo;
  GoogleButton(this.databaseRepo, this.initRepo);
}

class _GoogleButtonState extends State<GoogleButton> {
  bool _isProcessing = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey, width: 3),
        ),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: OutlineButton(
        highlightColor: Colors.blueGrey[100],
        splashColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],
        onPressed: () async {
          setState(() {
            _isProcessing = true;
          });
          await signInWithGoogle().then((result) {
            print(result);
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                fullscreenDialog: true,
                builder: (context) =>
                    MainPage(widget.databaseRepo, widget.initRepo),
              ),
            );
          }).catchError((error) {
            print('Registration Error: $error');
          });
          setState(() {
            _isProcessing = false;
          });
        },
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey, width: 3),
        ),
        highlightElevation: 0,
        // borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey, width: 3),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
          child: _isProcessing
              ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                    Colors.blueGrey,
                  ),
                )
              : Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                      child: Text(
                        'Bejelentkezés',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your height in ButtonTheme,like this

```
return ButtonTheme( 
        minWidth: 200.0,
         height: 200.0, 
          child:DecoratedBox()
      );
```

Comment: It still takes up the whole screen

Comment: Check again now I am set main return widget,I updates my answer.its make useful for you

Comment: still no, sorry :(

Comment: Can you added full code,means where you added google button widget